# How to set up log level for gwt compiler in eclipse

Tags: gwt, eclipse-kepler

```
Eclipse: Kepler
Google Plugin: 3.7 
GWT: 2.5.1
```

I do not see the option to set up the log level. I read that there should be Advanced button once we click in 'g" button, but that is not the case.

Can not post the image :(
Here is what i see in drop down of 'g':

```
New Web Application Project ...
Import App Engine Sample Apps ..
Import Apps Script Project ...
Import Google Hosted Project...
---
GWT Compile Project...
Profile Using Speed Tracer...
---
Deploy to App Engine...
---
Add Google APIs...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project > Google > GWT compile > Advanced

Comment: oh yeah.. I was looking on dropdown of 'g'. Thanks.